# I want to mock a FILE in ANSI C with a custom implementation of FILE

Tags: c, file-io, buffer, stdout

To test stdio i want to write a helper that opens a FILE that behaves like a file but in reality only has 100 chars fixed memory that i can access directly like a regular buffer.

Essentially something like the folowing.

```
TEST( printfMock, happyPath )
{
    const unsigned size = 100;
    char buffer[size];
    const char helloStackoverflow = "Hello Stackoverflow";
    FILE * mock, backup;

    backup = stdout; 
    mock = helper(buffer, suze);
    printf("%s", helloStackoverflow);
    stdout = backup;
    cleanup(mock);

    EXPECT_STREQ(helloStackoverflow, buffer);

}
```

I need some documentation on how to implement the `helper` function.
This function is meant to run on windows exclusively.

Comment: Why do you need to test stdio?

Comment: Any why would such a test ever need to write directly to a memory buffer rather than using something much easier, such as pipes...

Comment: I am wrapping the system for an experiment. I am routing calls through a common interface, one of its end is stdout and i would like to test that the common interface did not destroy the common functionality of stdio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FILE *mock represents a pointer to a [File Descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor). The FD is passed to the operating system to perform I/O's on devices or files. You therefore need a driver that will make a memory buffer act as a device or file. Such drivers exist for both Windows and Linux. I really do not envision doing this in any other way.

Comment: not quite what i hoped to hear but i read your link and i think you are correct. Thanks for the hint.